# Get the number of open tabs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, tabs

While using Firefox I want to keep tabs on the number of open tabs (pun intended). Is there a way to quickly get this number while using the browser?

In older versions of Firefox there was a pop up message box "You are going to close 428 tabs. Are you sure you want to proceed?" showing when you attempt to close the browser window. However in the later versions (I am running Firefox 102) it does not show up any more.

On this site I found [a related post with an answer for Google Chrome browser](https://superuser.com/a/1683965/128116) that uses Google sync function to get this number by typing a special url in the location string.

There is also [a related post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884363/how-to-extract-number-of-currently-opened-tabs) but the solutions there tend to require some scripting or enabling developer tools that are disabled by default.

What would be an easy way to get the number of currently open tabs in Firefox?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are ways to count tabs without any extensions, but they're less comfortable or require manual changes. For example:

- <kbd>Right mouse button</kbd> on a tab -> `Select All Tabs` -> <kbd>Right mouse button</kbd> on a tab again -> there will be `Close X` button with the number of opened tabs.

---

- you could modify the `V` ("List all tabs") dropdown button to include tab count with [custom styling](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/s4wsww/comment/hsts9ku/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button):

> ```css
> #TabsToolbar-customization-target {  
>   counter-reset: tabCount;  
> }
>
> .tabbrowser-tab {  
>   counter-increment: tabCount;  
> }
>
> #alltabs-button > .toolbarbutton-badge-stack > .toolbarbutton-icon {  
>   visibility: collapse !important;  
> }
>
> #alltabs-button > .toolbarbutton-badge-stack {  
>   position: relative !important;  
> }
>
> #alltabs-button > .toolbarbutton-badge-stack::before {  
>   content: counter(tabCount);  
>   border-bottom: 1px solid var(--toolbarbutton-icon-fill);  
>   color: var(--toolbarbutton-icon-fill);  
>   opacity: var(--toolbarbutton-icon-fill-opacity);  
>   position: absolute;  
>   bottom: var(--toolbarbutton-inner-padding);  
>   left: 50%;  
>   transform: translateX(-50%);  
>   padding: 0 3px;  
> }
> ```

Check e.g. [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1785228/1145698) to learn how to apply the styling.

Answer (score 11):

Enable the command line of the [Browser Console](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_console/index.html). Execute the following snippet.

```js
(()=>{
  const { ExtensionParent } = ChromeUtils.importESModule("resource://gre/modules/ExtensionParent.sys.mjs");
  const { tabTracker } = ExtensionParent.apiManager.global;
  console.log(tabTracker._tabIds.size)
})();
```

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to re-enable the Firefox 93 behaviour of warning when you close a window with multiple tabs. The setting for this can be found in the Tabs section of the General settings; simply tick the "Confirm before closing multiple tabs" checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

This requires an add-on. See the following:

- [Tab Counter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-counter-webext/)
  Add a badge to the toolbar that shows the number of currently open tabs in a window or all windows.
- [Tab Counter Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-counter-plus/)
  Shows the number of tabs in each window. Efficient and customizable.